# Accept download pop up with Selenium C# in IE 11 browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

While download Excel file using Internet Explorer,

I want to Accept 'Yes' on download popup. I am using C# and Selenium web driver.

Comment: Please help for same

Comment: What is the default selection?

Comment: @marwaha. ks: default selection on cancel button

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240146/selenium-download-file-in-internet-explorer-to-specified-folder-without-direct/48240157#48240157

Answer (score 0):

Try this to catch alert window :

```
 public static void CatchAlertAndAccept(IWebDriver d, bool isAccept)
    {
        IAlert simpleAlert = d.SwitchTo().Alert();

        if (isAccept == true)
        {
            simpleAlert.Accept();
        }
        else
        {
            simpleAlert.Dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not alert box. its window's save dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait({TAB});
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait({ENTER});
```

The tab will change the selection to 'Yes' from 'cancel' and the enter should submit the selection.

Comment: Also is this is not what you're looking for, can you provide a screen shot?